# How to refresh the list when Data changed on Sorting - SwipeListView(react-native-swipe-list-view)

Tags: react-native

I am using **SwipeListView** for Listing with **Swipe** options

I need to sort the list of Items **ascending/descending**

*Sorting* functions are done but the list is not refresh

```
const [productSortList, setProductSortList] = useState(productArraylist);
```

`productArraylist` -> main array list from api

`productSortList` -> temporary array list to store sorting data

```
               <SwipeListView
                //useFlatList={true}
                ListEmptyComponent={FlatlistEmpty()}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                // useNativeDriver={false}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                data={productSortList}
                renderItem={renderProduct}
                renderHiddenItem={renderHiddenItem1}
                // leftOpenValue={73}
                rightOpenValue={-345}
                previewRowKey={productSortList[0].id}
                previewOpenValue={-400}
                previewOpenDelay={1000}
                extraData={productSortList}
                // onRowDidOpen={onItemOpen}
              />
```

In **FlatList** `extraData={Our List Array}` will do the refresh when the **data** get change.

How to do with **SwipeListView**

Comment: create a function to sort the list, use this function initially when you are loading the List, and again call the same sort function on refresh with new data after refresh

Comment: Yes I have a sorting function and that functions are working find on each click, but how to refresh the ListvIew?

Comment: need to use pull to refresh?